# error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types

Tags: rust, substrate

I run ibc-rs(https://github.com/octopus-network/ibc-rs/tree/feature/ics20), at branch feature/ics20. run this command : `cargo build -p ibc`. Get this below error. before this have this error, but now I reconstruct mac computer this error, yet occur.

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> /Users/suyinrong/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7834a41d734f0c1d/902587b/primitives/runtime-interface/src/impls.rs:45:1
   |
45 | assert_eq_size!(usize, u32);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `usize` (64 bits)
   = note: target type: `u32` (32 bits)
   = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq_size` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> /Users/suyinrong/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7834a41d734f0c1d/902587b/primitives/runtime-interface/src/impls.rs:47:1
   |
47 | assert_eq_size!(*const u8, u32);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `*const u8` (64 bits)
   = note: target type: `u32` (32 bits)
   = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq_size` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0512`.
error: could not compile `sp-runtime-interface` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

My env:

```
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/suyinrong/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-02-17-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.58-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

1.58-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/Volumes/Seagate Basic/octopus/ibc-rs/rust-toolchain.toml')
rustc 1.58.1 (db9d1b20b 2022-01-20)
```

Comment: [Is this related?](https://github.com/informalsystems/ibc-rs/pull/1390#issuecomment-949281625)

Comment: thx, let me try.

Comment: Hello mate. Anything you passed it through?